# How To Use MVC PHP With Case Sensitive?

Tags: php, url-routing

I am creating website in PHP. I am using MVC in PHP. My website works like this, if user go to example.com/about then it it will load About class and index() function. If user will go to localhost/about/founder then it will load founder() function from About class. but the thing is that if I go to localhost/About or localhost/AbOut or anything like that it is loading default index() function from About class file. So what to do with case sensitivity? I mean I want my script to load index() function from class file if it is localhost/about or localhost/terms. If anything is in uppercase, then it should load 404 error function. 404 error function is already set in my site.

Please help me friends.

here is my Bootstrap.php class file

```
<?php

/* 
    Bootstrap class to run functions by URL
*/

class Bootstrap {

    public $_req;
    public $_body;
    public $_file;
    public $_error;

    function __construct(){
        if(empty($_GET['req'])){
            require 'classes/home.php';
            $this->_body = new Home();

            $this->hdr($this->_body->head());
            $this->_body->index();
            $this->ftr();
            exit();
            }

            $this->_req = rtrim($_GET['req'], '/');
            $this->_req = explode('/', $this->_req );

            $_file = 'classes/'.$this->_req[0].'.php';

            if(file_exists($_file)){
                require $_file;
            }
            else {
                $this->error(404);
                 }

            $this->_body = new $this->_req[0];
            $this->hdr($this->_body->head());


            if(isset($this->_req[2])){
                if(method_exists($this->_req[0], $this->_req[1])){
                    $this->_body->{$this->_req[1]}($this->_req[2]);
                    }else {
                    $this->error(404);
                    }
            }else {
                if(isset($this->_req[1])){
                    if(method_exists($this->_req[0], $this->_req[1])){
                        $this->_body->{$this->_req[1]}();
                        }else {
                        $this->error(404);
                        }
                }else {
                $this->_body->index();
                }

            $this->ftr();
            }                   
        }

    //this function is to set header in html code
    public function hdr($var = false){
        echo '<!DOCTYPE HTML><html><head>'.$var.'</head><body>';
    }

    //this function is tp set footer in html code
    public function ftr($var = false){
        echo $var.'</body></html>';
    }

    //error handler
    public function error($var){
        require 'classes/er_pg.php';
        $this->_error = new Error();
        $this->_error->index($var);

        }
}
```

Comment: check url in Index method itself or make one standard - every url lowercase and check it in router. Or just.. ignore it. someone entered localhost/tERMS. so what? :]

Comment: What is up in this question to have 2 close flag and a vote down?

Comment: @viral4ever Most website (stackoverflow too...), even banks don't care about case in URL's.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use anything to load non-lowercase URLs because of the duplicate content, and that's a good thing you're doing. The wrong URLs should fail automatically in such cases.

However, since you didn't show how are you making those calls, then only thing I can suggest at this point is to check if the called method exists (case-sensitive), and if not, throw/redirect to a 404 page (`header($_SERVER["SERVER_PROTOCOL"]." 404 Not Found");`).

---

UPDATE

After all the chat in the comments, seems like `file_exists` is not case-sensitive in your case, which is really weird. Hopefully someone will be able to figure it out so I can delete this (keeping it because of the info in the comments).

Comment: Please check my question once again as I've updated with codes.

Comment: Hm, seems fine at a first glance. What does `var_dump($this->_req);` output?

Comment: Fatal error: Class 'var_dump' not found in Bootstrap.php on line 37
 which is $this->_body = new var_dump($this->_req[0]);

Comment: Huh? Where did you put it? Just put the var_dump line I gave you after you define $this->_req (below those two lines). You can add `die();` after.

Comment: sorry, I did as you said. so at localhost/home I got "array(1) { [0]=> string(4) "home" }" and at localhot/Home I got "array(1) { [0]=> string(4) "Home" }"

Comment: I tired with localhost/About and localhost/about and got array(1) { [0]=> string(5) "About" } and array(1) { [0]=> string(5) "about" } result. So what to do with it? And I am trying to make something professional. So if you can suggest me some other things or tutorials then it will be helpful for me. I am still learning. And I want to create something like wordpress and facebook and google and all. So if possible, let me know.

Comment: Can you check what `file_exists('about.php')` and `file_exists('aBOUt.php')` return (add paths)? It should fail there. Also, are you sure your error(404) method works?

Comment: I tried it in default home.php file. I used Home.php and it worked. No error or nothing else happened.

Comment: `var_dump(file_exists('classes/aBOUt.php'));` should do it.

Comment: So I got 404 error when I used var_dump(file_exists($_file))

Comment: That shouldn't do it, you shouldn't use var_dump for anything else but outputting/debugging something. Tell me what it outputs, put it wherever you want, and make sure you put `die();` after, just like you did earlier.

Comment: When i tried to access localhost/about i got "bool(true) Page not found." and when i tried to use localhost/About, I got same error.

Comment: Alright, for some weird reason, your file_exists function is not case sensitive (or you really have both about and About files). What OS are you using?

Comment: nope, i have about.php and its codes are
<?php class About {
 function __construct(){} 
 
 public function index(){
  echo 'This is about page.';
  }
} that's it. I am using xampp in windows.

Comment: Any chance you have an About directory there? I'm really not sure what's going on. If so, replace your file_exist() function with is_file().

Comment: Nope. In my rooot directory, there are only two directory called "classes" and "config"

Comment: there are only three files. home.php, anout.php and error.php as I just started working on this app. no upper case in name of files.

Comment: Hmm, I really have no idea why it fails then... The last thing I can suggest is to try is_file instead of file_exists, but I doubt it would fix it.

Comment: Nope, it didn't work. Anyways, thank you for helping me. :D i appreciate your help. DO you have any suggestion for me? Do you know how it works with fb.com/help instead of fb.com/HelP

Comment: Well, that's the normal behaviour, not sure about their implementation though. Last question: are you able to open both home and about pages?

Comment: Yes, I can open same. There no error after changing is_file

Comment: So they both work perfectly... And you're sure the code you posted here is exactly the same as the one you're using?

Comment: yes. I posted same codes which I am using in my Bootstrap.php file

Comment: Ok, last question :D How are you translating between localhost/about and localhost/?req=about (or whatever you have)?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem. I used this

```
if(ctype_lower($this->_req[0])){
            $_file = 'classes/'.$this->_req[0].'.php';
```

and now its working. Thanx anyways friends.